# Double Values Increases Randomly

Tags: java

The double Value increases randomly.

```
for(double i=-1;i<=1;i+=0.1)
{
for(double j=-1;j<=1;j+=0.1)
{
//logic
system.out.print(i);
system.out.print(j);
}
}


Here, the value comes like: 
-1, -0.9, -0.8, -0.69, -0.51 ....-0.099 , 1.007 (WHY, U ARE GREATER THAN 1)
```

The output is not same but kind of this.

But, I want the exact values only. WHat should I do ??

Comment: Maybe you should be using `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: [Do not use floating point variables as loop counters](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM09-J.+Do+not+use+floating-point+variables+as+loop+counters)

Comment: I want one in the answer.

Comment: double is 52bit precision

Comment: Notwithstanding the answers that (correctly) point out that floating point is inexact, I simply DO NOT BELIEVE that that code would produce those numbers.  An error of `0.007` from ~20 floating point additions using `double` is implausible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an integer counter, and multiply to get the double:

```
for(int i = -10; i <= 10; i++) {
  double iDouble = 0.1 * i;
  ....
}
```

The double will still have rounding error - that is inevitable - but the rounding error will not affect the loop count.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get exact values do to the limitations of doubles. They can't always represent **exactly** the decimal you want, and they have precision errors. In your case you may want to cast the double to an int for the double comparison, but as @alex said you shouldn't be doing this.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way that doubles are stored in memory, they are only exact if the fractional part is a negative power of two, e.g. 0, 1/2, 1/4, etc. This is also why you should never use equality statements for doubles, but rather > and <. For exact calculations, you could use BigDecimal:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(123.45);
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(new BigDecimal(123.45));
System.out.println(bigDecimal.floatValue()); // prints 246.9
```

Comment: More precisely, if the fractional part is an integer multiplied by a power of two. 3.0/4.0 is exact.

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM09-J.+Do+not+use+floating-point+variables+as+loop+counters), floating-point variables must not be used as loop counters. Limited-precision IEEE 754 floating-point types cannot represent:

- all simple fractions exactly
- all decimals precisely, even when the decimals can be represented in a small number of digits.
- all digits of large values, meaning that incrementing a large floating-point value might not change that value within the available precision.

(...) **Using floating-point loop counters can lead to unexpected behavior.**

Instead, use integer loop counter and increment another variable inside this loop like this:

```
for (int count = 1; count <= 20; count += 1) {
  double x = -1 + count * 0.1;
  /* ... */
}
```